# Using Linq against EF filter for null on numberic field

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In a database you can have NULL for a field that is a number. When I bring that table into my project via EF and put a null check on that column in a where clause it gives me info saying it will always be true and that you can't check null on a decimal as it's never equal to null. This however would be valid in direct sql. How can I check for null on a numeric column in the database thru EF and is this just a misunderstanding between EF and databases?

example where caluse:

```
&& l.latitude != null && l.longitude != null
```

latitude and longitude are decimals when they come into EF but they can be NULL in the database and I want to filter those out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that even though the database supports `null` for those columns, you've mapped them to a non-nullable type: `decimal`.  I believe that this causes `null` values to be defaulted to zero in your case, which is probably not what you want.

The correct solution is to fix your entity to use `decimal?` so that `null` values are supported correctly.

Comment: I didn't map them myself, EF did automatically. I'll check the DB as I would assign EF is deciding what to do based on the nullable flag on the columns in the DB.